# move a field into its neighbor

Tags: json, jq

I would like to merge some nested objects in array but without pointing elements numbers because CPU numbers may vary.
DEsired output may be similar. I would like to end up with metric and value as one object which allow me to present it in one log line.

Can somebody give me a hand here.

Regards, Jay

**Initial output:**

```
{
  "resultType": "vector",
  "result": [
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu10",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "iowait"
      },
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "8,466666666790843"
      ]
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu11",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "nice"
      },
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu9",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "steal"
      },
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu6",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "steal"
      },
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu8",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "nice"
      },
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu1",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "softirq"
      },
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "1,233333333414824"
      ]
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu4",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "guest"
      },
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "0"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Desired output:**

```
{
  "resultType": "vector",
  "result": [
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu10",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "iowait"
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "8,466666666790843"
      ]
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu11",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "nice"
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu9",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "steal"
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu6",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "steal"
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu8",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "nice"
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu1",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "softirq"
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "1,233333333414824"
      ]
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "cpu": "cpu4",
        "instance": "hostname-1",
        "job": "node",
        "mode": "guest"
      "value": [
        1584371948,
        66,
        "0"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You should show some code of what you have attempted and ask a specific question if you are having a problem with that.

Comment: I tried so many pointless, basic things that listing them here would be embarrassing for me. My logical thinking at such "programming" problems is close to none. Trying to learn...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each result separate value field and add it to metric in a new object; and update the array with them.

```
jq '.result[] |= {metric: (.metric + {value})}' file
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you. I am glad and sad because I wasn't even close to develop such query.

Comment: @Js_good Learning JQ's syntax is a bit challenging but pays well in the end. You're welcome